# How do I change how the results are displayed in this character sorter code?

Tags: javascript, css

I don't know any javascript or CSS but I'm wondering if there's a simple way for the results of this character sorter script I found could be displayed the way I want it. Currently, it lists all the results vertically, with the top 3 showing their image. The way I'd like it to show is that it displays the top 3 horizontally and the rest (which is just the text) vertically.

Example how it is currently:

Result 1 [Shows Image]

Result 2 [Shows Image]

Result 3 [Shows Image]

Result 4

Result 5

Result 6

And example how I want it:

Result 1 [Shows Image] - Result 2 [Shows Image] - Result 3 [Shows Image] - Result 4 (And Result 5, 6 and so on are UNDER Result 4.)

Here's the code:

```
str_CenterT = 'Tie!';
str_CenterB = 'Undo last choice';

str_ImgPath = 'http://i.imgur.com/';
var bln_ResultMode = 1;
var int_ResultImg = 2;
var int_ResultRank = 3;


var bln_ResultStyle = 0;


var bln_ProgessBar = 1;


var int_Colspan = 2;
var ary_TitleData = [
   "Male",
   "Female",
];
var ary_CharacterData = [
   [1, "Calem",         [1,0], "kp5zFMC.png"],
   [1, "Leaf",      [0,1], "AYiQoyc.png"],
   [1, "Hilbert",       [1,0], "SAuywcW.png"],
   [1, "DP Lucas",          [1,0], "EfM0nPQ.png"],
   [1, "Nate",          [1,0], "CyTtmPk.png"],
   [1, "FRLG Red",          [1,0], "5hv7HDF.png"],
   ];
```

**Edit:** I guess there's more to the code than this.

http://static.tumblr.com/8blsvta/AAUmlpa5y/mod_k-factory.js

http://static.tumblr.com/8blsvta/exTmlpa6o/fnc_main_v3.js

Answer (score 0):

I'd really like to see how your are displaying your data. But you could try wrapping the results in a div element and simply write some CSS.

Imagine you have this:

```
<div class="someClass">
     <ul>
        <li> outputting data </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Then in your css:

```
.someClass{
     display:inline-block
}
```

Note:

You can also try with

```
.someClass {
    display: flex
}
```

This will work in modern browsers only.

Comment: I only see an empty Tumblr account :D

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty lost here. From what I understand I should wrap the div code around the "ShowData" section in fnc_main_v3.js, but I'm not sure where exactly to start it and where to end it in the code. I don't know where exactly I should place the CSS code either. I can tell you that clicking "Edit HTML" leads me to where I can edit the source code of that page I linked and I have a vague idea that that is where I should put the CSS.

Comment: That's odd, it's working for me. I got another one here: http://pokesmsorter.tumblr.com/